# How to convert wav to ogg and mp3 using VBR

Tags: sound, mp3, convert, wav

How to convert wav to ogg and to mp3 with VBR and excellent end quality?

If possible, using `soundconverter` or `ffmpeg`.

Incidentally, I tried to see whether `soundconverter` uses VBR and there is nothing about it in the GUI preferences, so it is not clear. Does it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For MP3, I strongly suggest using [Lame](https://lame.sourceforge.io/)[image: Install Lame], considered by many (including me) *THE* best MP3 encoder, specially for VBR:

```
sudo apt-get install lame
```

And to encode:

```
lame -V 5 file.wav file.mp3
```

This will create a high-quality MP3 VBR file around ~130kbps, which is great for casual listening. Use `-V 3` for average bitrates around ~200kbps.

If you want to create id3v1 and id3v2 tags at the same time, you can use:

```
lame -V 5 --add-id3v2 --pad-id3v2 --ignore-tag-errors --ta artist --tl album --tt title --tn track --ty year --tg genre --tc comment file.wav file.mp3
```

For Ogg, the most traditional encoder is [Vorbis](https://xiph.org/vorbis/)[image: Install Vorbis]:

```
sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools
```

And to encode:

```
oggenc -q 3 -o file.ogg file.wav
```

Ogg is VBR by default. `-q 3` stands for default quality, you may change 3 from -1 to 10, or omit the option. Also, output file is optional. If you omit `-o file.ogg` it will automatically create a file with same name as input and .ogg extension. It also supports multiple input files (you can encode several at once, for example, using *.wav).

And for tagging:

```
oggenc -a artist -t title -l album -G genre -c comment -o file.ogg file.wav
```

Last but not least, since you seem to be very interested in encoding, an amazing forum for audio technical details and awesome source of knowledge is [HydrogenAudio](https://hydrogenaud.io/).

---

And, for GUI, you said it yourself: [`soundconverter`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kKUz.png) is a great choice. It does have VBR for MP3 (for Ogg, its the format's default, so don't worry).

[image: Screenshot of SoundConverter]

Answer (score 2):

For Variable bitrate in OGG format, transform it with ffmpeg which is avconv on Ubuntu ([see here for difference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1995559))

```
avconv -i inputFileName -c:a libvorbis -qscale [0-255] targetFileName.ogg
```

### Quality for qscale option

- 0: worst quality
- 255: best quality

  #### Which one to choose

My tests results are followings

- <= 6 is the quality <= 192kb/s and a difference could be listened, but for voice 1 is sufficient and from a flac music file (which is lossless file format) @ 5 I cannot tell the difference
- For High quality music prefer values upper than 8. But from a flac >10 the file size was not higher, and for the following example, I cannot tell the difference after 8 even with strong bass and trebles.

#### Results of testings from a flac file

From a recording of an album I think is a reference in term of recording and mastering quality, preceding digits are the qscale values, sizeof file and resulting bitrate

```
0_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 2.7M 65 kb/s
1_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 3.3M 81 kb/s
2_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 4.1M 100 kb/s
3_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 4.8M 116 kb/s
4_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 5.4M 131 kb/s
5_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 6.9M 169 kb/s
6_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 8.5M 209 kb/s
7_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 11M 248 kb/s
8_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 12M 294 kb/s
9_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 15M 365 kb/s
10_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
11_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
12_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
13_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
14_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
15_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
16_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
17_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
18_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
19_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
20_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
21_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
22_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
23_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
24_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
25_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
26_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
27_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
28_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
29_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
30_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
31_Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.ogg 20M 491 kb/s
Michael_Jackson-Dangerous_01.Jam.flac 39M
```